NoSuchAlgorithmException while reading elliptic curve key based p12 file from raw resources of android in android application
I am trying to read elliptic curve key-based PKCS#12 file using the  BouncyCastle provider. But it is throwing the following exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: exception decrypting data - java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.12 SecretKeyFactory not available

The PKCS#12 file was generated by the following commands that use OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023:
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out ec-private.key
openssl req -new -key ec-private.key -out ec-certificate.csr
openssl x509 -req -in ec-certificate.csr -signkey ec-private.key -days 365 -out ec-certificate.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out ec-certificate.p12 -inkey ec-private.key -in ec-certificate.crt -name "My ECC Certificate"

My corresponding code is given below.
try {
    InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ec_certificate);
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    // Initialize KeyStore
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");

    //KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keyStore.load(caInput, password_.toCharArray());
    Enumeration < String > aliases = keyStore.aliases();
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
        String alias = aliases.nextElement();
        cert = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (CertificateException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (KeyStoreException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

How can i resolve the issue using BouncyCastle provider?
I am using group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk18on', version: '1.76' bouncycastle dependency.
In my java version i am using group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk18on', version: '1.79' bouncycastle dependency and the runtime exception not thrown. It only throws while using in my android application and reading from raw resource file.

I am using OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023.
I created the p12 file using following 4 command
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out ec-private.key
openssl req -new -key ec-private.key -out ec-certificate.csr
openssl x509 -req -in ec-certificate.csr -signkey ec-private.key -days 365 -out ec-certificate.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out ec-certificate.p12 -inkey ec-private.key -in ec-certificate.crt -name "My ECC Certificate"

That's weird; Bouncy has supported PBKDF2 by OID for a long time. Is this really Bouncy not Spongy? (Though it shouldn't make a difference.) You can probably avoid the problem by adding -legacy on pkcs12 -export (in 3.0 up), though it reduces key confidentiality slightly (and cert a lot unless you also add -descert but certs don't need to be secret). Or less conveniently and with similar result specify -keypbe x and -certpbe x with a pre-PBES2 scheme. It would be nice to debug this but I don't know how on android.

I have been able to reproduce the issue using OpenSSL 3.2.1 and Bouncy Castle 1.79 on the Android emulator. I believe the problem is caused by the fact there is already a provider with the name of "BC" that ships with Android, and that provider shadows the modern one you want to use in your app. I tried two different workarounds that seemed to work, but I didn't do extensive testing. The first workaround is to simply remove the existing Bouncy Castle provider prior to adding your version. So
InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ec_certificate);
Security.removeProvider("BC");
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

// Initialize KeyStore
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");

The second workaround is to use the getInstance method that takes a Provider instance as the second argument. So use instead
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", new BouncyCastleProvider());

There is a long history of Android using bits and pieces of the Bouncy Castle provider, and that causing problems with apps trying to use their own copies of more up-to-date versions of Bouncy Castle. I though that was all ancient history but evidently there are still some remnants of those days.
